# Mount writable NTFS disk in Ubuntu Core

Tags: ntfs, ubuntu-core

I have recently installed Ubuntu Core on a Raspberry Pi 3 using the official images provided by Canonical. I have a USB hard drive connected to the Raspberry Pi. This drive is formatted as NTFS. In order to mount the external drive in Ubuntu Core during the boot process I have created the file `/etc/systemd/system/media-data.mount` with the content below:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount unit for data

[Mount]
What=/dev/disk/by-uuid/4E1AEA7B1AEA6007
Where=/media/data
Type=ntfs
Options=rw

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I can see the data contained in the external drive, but can't create new files  or modify existing ones even with the root user. Is it possible that NTFS write support in not enabled by default in Ubuntu Core?

I have tried to mount the NTFS disk using:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/disk/by-uuid/4E1AEA7B1AEA6007 /mnt
```

But this returns:

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'ntfs-3g'
```

It seems that `ntfs-3g` is not installed and I don't know how to install it without 'apt install'. I have used Linux for a long time, but I'm new to `snaps` and ubuntu-core, so I'm trying to understand the best way to deal with problems like this. Any help would be useful.

Comment: what is the output of "ls -l" on /media ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few different options here:

1. If `ntfs-3g` is installed, then you can just use the following instead of mount:

   ```
   $ ntfs-3g /dev/disk/by-uuid/4E1AEA7B1AEA6007 /mnt
   ```

   You can check if it installed with `dpkg -l | grep ntfs-3g` or `sudo snap list | grep ntfs-3g`
2. If `ntfs-3g` isn't installed, then you can install it with `sudo snap install ntfs-3g`
3. Finally, I know on at least Arch or Redhat that you don't have to explicitly run `mount` with the `ntfs-3g` type option as it looks in `/usr/bin/mount.ntfs`, which is just symlinked to `/usr/bin/ntfs-3g` if `ntfs-3g` is installed. So you can just run:

   ```
   $ sudo mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/4E1AEA7B1AEA6007 /mnt
   ```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I suppose the solution should be nearer. I have tried to install the `ntfs-3g` snap, but I can't  find a stable snap with that name. The command `sudo snap install ntfs-3g` returns `error: cannot install "ntfs-3g": snap not found`. Is it an stable snap? How can I find it if  is not in the stable channel?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Ubuntu Core:

> Options=umask=0007

For more details you can check:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/systemd.mount.5.html
and
https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount

Also for someone reading this thread it is worth mentioning that for auto mount to work you need to execute:

> sudo systemctl daemon-reload
>
> sudo systemctl start media-data.mount
>
> sudo systemctl enable media-data.mount

after creating the

> /etc/systemd/system/media-data.mount

For details checkout this thread: https://flexion.org/posts/2016-12-raspberry-pi-3-powered-nextcloud-box-on-ubuntu-core/

Comment: The option `umask=0111` didn't work for me. I don't think this is a permissions problem, because I can't write to the partition even with the root user. I already knew the link about nextcloud on ubuntu core because it's just what I want to do, but notice that in your link the hard drive is formatted as ext4 and the problem is with NTFS. I still haven't found the `nfts-3g` snap proposed by @grayson-kent.